# Applying a style to a gridview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, styles

I have been tearing my hair out all afternoon on this, hopefully someone can help me. Bear with me on this one.

I have a number of styles in my App.xaml which transforms a gridview, the code looks like this.

```
<Application.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      Focusable="false">
                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                                        Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </DockPanel>

                        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Background="{Binding Path=Background,ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar}"
                               LastChildFill="false">
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Width="1"
                                   Fill="White"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                   Height="1"
                                   Fill="White"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewHeaderRowPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
                        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White"/>

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFE3F7FF" x:Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1" x:Name="HeaderContent" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                        <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Margin="1,1,0,0" x:Name="HeaderHoverBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"/>
                        <Border Margin="1,0,0,1" x:Name="HeaderPressBorder" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"/>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, this is applying to ALL gridviews on my page, how would i make these styles apply to certain gridviews and not others? I have tried a million different ways and i'm sure i'm missing something obvious!, please help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your Key a string, like `<Style x:Key="myGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">`, then call that style for the grids you want to use it on.  Also, if you only set a TargetType and not a Key, then it will be the default for that Type everywhere, unless you override it.

Comment: @Smoore I did think about that but it's a lot of keys i'd have to add to one grid, is there no way to bunch them all up into one key?

Comment: Yeah, that is.  Perhaps you could make this Gird a UserControl, and just build this Grid in there the way you like it, then use this control wherever you need to throughout your project.

Comment: Since they are separate controls, they all have to have separate keys, so the only way to bunch them into one key is to group them all into one control.  Are all of these controls part of the ListView control?  If so, why couldn't you just have one ListView style with all of these things defined within it?

Comment: Well as far as i can tell they are all part of the Listview/Gridview, but not to sure how to bunch them up into one ListView Style, I got these from another site to help me position the gridview how i want it :-p